# html width (100% -n px)?

Tags: html, css

On an HTML page, I have two columns.  I have the widths set to 75% for column 1 and 25% for column 2.  I set the width using `style='width:75%;'`.  My columns are set up as div's as I understand it is considered poor practice to use tables for layout.

My question is, can I make one column have a fixed width (eg. 200px) and the other column automatically take up the remainder width of the browser window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, you can achieve this very simply by using margins. An example of this would be as follows:

```
 #wrapper { overflow:hidden; }

 #right 
 {
     float:right;
     display:inline;
     width: [Fixed Width]px;
 }

 #left 
 {
     margin-right:[Fixed Width]px;
     display:inline;
 }
```

Then HTML markup as follows:

```
 <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="right">Test</div>
     <div id="left">Test</div>
 </div>
```

This will work in IE6+, and all of the major browsers I know of. The "display:inline" is so that extra margins can be added if you so desire in IE6.

It works because the float is took out of the normal flow of the page, so the "#left" will always take up whatever room is available. The wrapper is a quick clearing trick.

Comment: +1 for the `margin-right`, but why do you need the `display: inline`? Any element that is floated is automatically a block level element?

Comment: Its a fix for the double margin bug in IE6. Modern browsers will quite rightly ignore the display property for floated elements but IE6 does not. Say you added margin-left to #right (Silly I know, you would take the amount off margin-right on #left normally). This would stop the margin doubling up.

Answer (score 2):

A common solution is to float your fixed-width column left or right, and give the other column a margin equal or greater than the width of the fixed-width column.

By the way, if your column is a block level element like a `div`, you don´t have to set the width, it will automatically occupy all available space.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<table style="width:100%;">`.  Then one of your columns can have `width:200px` and the other will take up the remaining space.

Comment: Using tables for layout leads to pages filled with hard to read mark-up.

Comment: Every cross-browser "columns with CSS" solution I've seen (short of CSS3) is far more complicated and fragile than tables.  That said, I understand the moral objection.